# add android gridview items from right to left

Tags: android, gridview, layout

I want to make my gridview to add items from right to left,

I mean something like this:

> 3     2     1
>
> 6     5     4

so i added `android:rotationY="180"` to my gridview in my `main.xml`

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#ffffff"
android:gravity="center"
android:orientation="vertical" >
<GridView
    android:id="@+id/gridview"
    android:rotationY="180"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:columnWidth="90dp"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:verticalSpacing="10dp" />

  </LinearLayout>
```

Also I add it my `item.xml` which my `Adaptor`  using that :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:rotationY="180"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="5dp" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/gridimage"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="29dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:src="@drawable/folder_icon" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

But it it does not work,what should i do to make it to work?

Answer (score 2):

you should add `android:rotationY="180"` to your item.xml too

Comment: thank you Hamid, but as you see added it to my LinearLayout, is also need to add it on my ImageView?

Comment: no, that's it, but the problem is your Image-view, I use this and it works for me, but instead of Image-view I had text-view, if you can, use text-view instead of Image-view and set @drawable/folder_icon as the background of that. hope this help you

Comment: it doesn't work for me , could you please give me a example ?

Answer (score 1):

you can edit grid view's "Adapter" as following:

```
final Object object;
//move element at index 0 to index 2
if(position % 3 == 0 && items.size() > position +2){
    object = items.get(position + 2);
}
//move element at index 2 to index 0
else if(position % 3 == 2){
    object = items.get(position - 2);
}
//the element at index 1 still at index 1 (do nothing)
```

Note: this will work perfectly if you use "onClickListener" in the adapter instead of "onItemClickListener" for the grid view. Or you can use the same formula to get the selected position correctly. ;)

Hope this will help you =D